# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator is not running any API except SQL API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to connect Azure Cosmos DB emulator using command line with /EnableGremlinEndpoint. However the Cosmos DB Emulator never started. And if I run it without specifying any endpoint, it started and opened the page on browser.

I have even tried to run it with other endpoints, but in vain. How can I figure out this problem?

Comment: Can you post the exact command used to start the emulator? Also, make sure you're running the latest version of the emulator.

Comment: @MarkBrown here is the command: C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> CosmosDB.Emulator /EnableGremlinEndpoint

Comment: How do you know that the emulator isn't working? Did you try to connect to it with your app?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the emulator is working fine. The Explorer only appears when launching for SQL API because we don't run any of the OSS clients within the emulator.

Try connecting to the Gremlin endpoint via your Gremlin client and test a query to see if it's working.

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No Mark, I did not connect with my app. But it was not opening in the explorer, however it is opening now, but after some time I get a popup message and when I click ok, it shuts down.

[image]

I am trying to connect local cosmos emulator with tinkerpop gremlin console. I will update you on it.